# Multipart or base64 for AJAX file uploads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

I'm writing a single page application with EmberJS and need to upload a few files.

I wrote a special view, that wraps the file input field and extracts the first file selected. This lets me bind the `File`-Object to a model-attribute.

Now I have to choose.

I can write a special file transform, that serialises the `File`-Object to base64 and simply PUT/POST this.

Or I can intercept the `RESTAdapter` methods `createRecord` and `updateRecord` to check every model for `File`-Objects and switch the PUT/POST requests to `multipart/form-data` and send it with the help of `FormData`

Does one of these directions pose significant problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to evaluate the same concern for a Restful API I'm developing. In my opinion, the most ideal method would be to just use the RESTAdapter with base64 encoded data.

That being said, I had to use the multipart/form-data method in my case, because the data transfer is 30% higher when you base64 encode the file data. Since my API would be have to accept large (100MB+) files, I opted to have the POST method of the API to receive multipart form data, with the file and json data being one of the POST variables.

So, unless you need to upload large files like in my case, I'd recommend always sticking to the REST methods.

Comment: Yes, I did it with base64 now. Funny thing is, after I solved this problem, I read about w3c doing it like me, lol http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this myself, and ended up using a simple jQuery AJAX call using the `FormData` object.  My multi-select implementation (where one can drop multiple files at once) looks like this:

```
filesDidChange: function() {
  // Get FileList
  var $input = this.$('input'),
      fileList = $input.get(0).files;

  // Iterate files
  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var file = fileList[i],
      formData = new FormData();

    // Append information to FormData instance
    formData.append('attachment[title]', file.name);
    formData.append('attachment[file]', file);
    formData.append('attachment[post_id]', this.get('post.id'));

    // Send upload request
    Ember.$.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/attachments',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      success: makeSuccessHandler(this),
      error: makeErrorHandler(this)
    });
  }

  // Notify
  this.container.lookup('util:notification').notify('Uploading file, please wait...');

  // Clear FileList
  $input.val(null);
},
```